# Python: Simplest way to convert integer to a version number?

Tags: python-3.x, format, version

For example:

I have an integer of `20000` which equals version `02.00.00`

How do I format `20000` to get `02.00.00`?

I have tried converting to string and using format:

```
x = str(20000)
    '{}.{}.{}'.format(x[0:2], x[2:4], x[4:6])
```

but this way I get `20.00.0` when I want `2.00.00` or `02.00.00`.

Comment: Is this python? There are ways of specifying leading zeros and padding in the curly braces of the format string. Maybe look into that. Or just add a 0 to the front of the string first, that may get desired result

Comment: Yes, it's Python. I added it in the description now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the indices the other way around. Try this:

```
x = str(20000)
version_string = "{}.{}.{}".format(x[:-4], x[-4:-2], x[-2:])
print(version_string)
```

It will show the 4 digits in blocks of 2 digits each and the remaining string (leading part until index -4) as major version (first digit).

**Edit:** Removed upper bound for the first format parameter, so the first block can have arbitrary length.

Answer (score 0):

If your number is always 5 digits you can do it like this :

```
myString = "20000"
formatedString = '0' + s[:1] + '.' + s[1:3] + '.' + s[3:6]
print formatedString
```